# How do I save a drawing in a tableview after a user draws something in a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uiimageview

I have this code for my save button but now I need to show the drawing that was saved in the tableview. I have some parts of the table view controller done but to get the image to show and save in the tableview is where im stuck at. How would I do this? Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false


UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)



let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
let fileURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("image.png").path!
data?.writeToFile(fileURL, atomically: true)
}


//CODE EDITED 
//MasterViewControllerTableView

var myImages: [UIImage] = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    myImages.append(image)
}




override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
    return 1
}



 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return myImages.count
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{


    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))
    imageView.image = myImages[indexPath.row]
    cell2.addSubview(imageView)
    return cell2
}


// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

        }
    }



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40 //Some number to fit the image
}




override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear how you application is structured, but the basic idea is still the same.

Create an array of `UIImage` and add to the array each time an image is saved.

**Create Array** `var myImages: [UIImage] = [UIIMage]()`
(put this some place where either the `UIImageView` and the `UITableView` can access it).

**Add Image to Array**: `myImages.append(image)`

Then modify your `numberOfRowsInSection` to this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return myImages.count
}
```

Display an image in a cell like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40))
    imageView.image = myImages[indexPath.row]
    cel.addSubview(imageView)
    return cell
}
```

Modify the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to fit the image:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
    heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 40 //Some number to fit the image
}
```

This is just barebones of what you can do to achieve what you are looking for.

**Edit**

```
@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    //Save Image Here
    myImages.append(image)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
    let fileURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("image.png").path!
    data?.writeToFile(fileURL, atomically: true)
}
```

Comment: When I draw an image in my UIImageView and press save it doesnt save to the table view for some reason. I dont get any errors or crashes.

Comment: @coding22 How are you trying to access the image?

Comment: let fileURL = documentsURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("image.png").path!

Comment: I think I did that part wrong. I dont have an image until I draw something on the UIImageView and press save.

Comment: @coding22 Look at the code above. If you want to access it in the `tableView`, it is much easier to append the `UIImage` to an array and access the array when you need an image. `let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` then `myImages.append(image)`

Comment: I get an error for the line myImages.append(image) it says fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.

Comment: @coding22 can you please update your code above to reflect the changes?

Comment: @coding22 I updated the code above to include where to append the image. Remove the lines in the `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: I removed the lines in the viewDidappear and updated the code but nothing saves in the tableview.

Comment: Shouldnt I be saving whats in the UIImageView. I have an outlet for where the drawing takes place. Like this @IBOutlet weak var mainIMageView: UIImageView!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93405/discussion-between-coding22-and-caleb).